# Unity C#: Caching keyboard/controller state?

Tags: c#, caching, input, unity-game-engine, xna

I've just started with unity so please excuse any lack of knowledge. I began programming with microsoft's xna environment. I've now switched to unity but I'm having troubles. Xna had a "KeyboardState" feature that checked what buttons/keys were being pressed. I've heard Unity doesn't have the same feature so I was wondering how I can store/cache input for the past 15 frames. I've heard Event.KeyboardEvent and KeyCode might help but I'm lost. Can anyone please help???

Answer (score 1):

You're wanting to store or cache the input for 15 frames? I can tell you how to gather input, you can cache it from there if you'd like by storing it in a global `Keycode[]` array.

This code will print the key being pressed to your console.

```
void OnGUI() {
    Event e = Event.current;
    if (e.isKey){
        string key = e.keyCode.ToString();
        Debug.Log(key);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate over all possible keycodes to and store their value for future use:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class KeyboardState : MonoBehaviour {

    /// <summary>
    /// Keyboard input history, lower indexes are newer
    /// </summary>
    public List<HashSet<KeyCode>> history=new List<HashSet<KeyCode>>();


    /// <summary>
    /// How much history to keep?
    /// history.Count will be max. this value
    /// </summary>
    [Range(1,1000)]
    public int historyLengthInFrames=10;


    void Update() {
        var keysThisFrame=new HashSet<KeyCode>();
        if(Input.anyKeyDown)
            foreach(KeyCode kc in System.Enum.GetValues(typeof(KeyCode)))
                if(Input.GetKey(kc))
                    keysThisFrame.Add(kc);
        history.Insert(0, keysThisFrame);
        int count=history.Count-historyLengthInFrames;
        if(count > 0)
            history.RemoveRange(historyLengthInFrames, count);
    }


    /// <summary>
    /// For debug Purposes
    /// </summary>
    void OnGUI() {
        for(int ago=history.Count-1; ago >= 0; ago--) {
            var s=string.Format("{0:0000}:", ago);
            foreach(var k in history[ago])
                s+="\t"+k;
            GUILayout.Label(s);
        }
    }

}
```